# How to kill a process in a top?

Tags: process, kill, top

Unlike htop -- top is more difficult for me and I would to know how to kill any process in top ? Thank in advance my Stackoverflow friends !

Comment: I think you meant Unix & Linux? Stack Overflow is [over there](http://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Yes I mean Linux and Unix and I am in a right place @JeffSchaller !

Comment: Unix & Linux is a subsidiary of Stackoverflow isn't @JeffSchaller?

Comment: My understanding is that U&L, SO, and others are all subsidiary entities of Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Press `k` for kill and enter PID and signal to kill.

Some [common signals](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-kill-command-examples/#2):

| Number | Name (short name) | Description | Used for |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | SIGNULL (NULL) | Null | Check access to pid |
| 1 | SIGHUP (HUP) | Hangup | Terminate; can be trapped |
| 2 | SIGINT (INT) | Interrupt | Terminate; can be trapped |
| 3 | SIGQUIT (QUIT) | Quit | Terminate with core dump; can be trapped |
| 9 | SIGKILL (KILL) | Kill | Forced termination; cannot be trapped |
| 15 | SIGTERM (TERM) | Terminate | Terminate; can be trapped |
| 24 | SIGSTOP (STOP) | Stop | Pause the process; cannot be trapped. This is default if signal not provided to kill command. |
| 25 | SIGTSTP (STP) | Terminal | Stop/pause the process; can be trapped |
| 26 | SIGCONT (CONT) | Continue | Run a stopped process |

Comment: Which one of these is equivalent to hitting `Ctrl + C`?

Answer (score 1):

with this you close any process giving it the name

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Set process name: " PS
f() { ps ax | grep "$1" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9 &> /dev/null; }
f "$PS"
if [  $? -gt 0 ]; then
   echo "$PS" "was not found"
 else
   echo "$PS" "was successfully closed"
fi
```